# Amazon AWS RDS MySQL - Instances and Pricing

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have 15 databases that are running off my shared hosting account for $5/mnth. I would like to use AWS RDS.

1) Do I have to create a new INSTANCE for each database?

2) Won't this be expensive $191/mnth ($12.75/mnth x 15DBs for the cheapest db.t2.micro instance)? http://aws.amazon.com/rds/pricing/

3) How can I optimize the management of resources? (eg. Is putting more tables into a single DB instance the best solution?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No. One instance can host multiple databases. If they are used for different purposes, you will want to set up separate grants for each for security.
2. As i said in 1, you don't need to use multiple instances. Although depending on your workload, a micro may or may not be large enough.
3. That's a complicated question. Security requirements often come into play.

Comment: Great thanks! I will check out the different DB types to suit my requirements :)

Comment: My experience you will get better performance and cheaper cost by hosting on EC2 using an open source market place AMI like turney MySQL or Bitnami MySQL. I migrated recently and peformance is significantly better and you do not suffer the restricted role the so called RDS root user has (you will find you cant perform a number of environmental operations on RDS that you really should be able to)

Comment: @MikeMiller On the other hand, setting up replication and backup on an ec2 instance is more complex. Although yes, you don't get full access to everything on RDS, I have yet to find a case where that has caused an issue.

Comment: @datasage: Has for me although I can't actually remember a good example. Turnkey Linux offer a pretty rich backup utility that although charged for still comes in cheaper in total. They have a nice management console as well. I haven't tried replication on their platform but it is very easy on RDS. EC2 performance is still more bang for buck and you dont run a weird custom AWS flavour of MySQL. Also dont think you can run the Enterprise tools on RDS

Comment: I remembered an example - timezone!! It has to be in UTC - that's a pain